# minimum working example preamble in a separete file

Tags: preamble

**Context**

I have seen other posts on preambles in separate files, but they do not meet my needs because they do not include minimum working examples. In addition, when I look in [1], this is a pretty good example, but its not working for me.

Following the example in [1], I first create a file that I save as example.sty. This file contains the following:

```
\ProvidesPackage{example}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

%Header styles
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

%makes available the commands \proof, \qedsymbol and \theoremstyle
\usepackage{amsthm}

%Ruler
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

%Lemma definition and lemma counter
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

%Definition counter
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

%Corolary counter
\newtheorem{corolary}{Corolary}[section]

%Commands for naturals, integers, topology, hull, Ball, Disc, Dimension, boundary and a few more
\newcommand{\E}{{\mathcal{E}}}
\newcommand{\F}{{\mathcal{F}}}
...

%Example environment
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{examle}{Example}

%Example counter
\newcommand{\reiniciar}{\setcounter{example}{0}}
```

---

Next,  create a second file, which save as myBigProject.tex.

This file has

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{example}


\begin{document}
hello

\end{document}
```

---

The result is an error that reads,

```
Latex error! Missing \begin{document}."
```

**Queston**

How can I repair this error. Please provide a minimum working example. Please make certain to be explicit about the name of your *.sty file.

**Bibliography**

[1] https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/

Comment: Your .sty file as shown has `...` which would cause that error.  Also are you sure that you want `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` is the package really only ever used with documents using that legacy encoding and not UTF-8 ?

Comment: That latin thing is from [1].  I included it here verbatim from [1]. Without the ..., my file compiled without error. Problem solved.

Comment: The error would highlight that line. You almost certainly do not want latin 1 now (overleaf like other current latex installations defaults to utf-8) That is an old document that you are referencing, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error message is

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.49 .
      ..
?
```

highlighting the `...` on line 49 of your file. You can not have typeset text in a package, before `\begin{document}`. Simply delete this line.

You should also delete

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

as this means that the package always resets the default encoding to the legacy latin1 encoding instead of UTF-8.